# Java "global" object

Tags: java, object, global

I'm writing a game in Java. Is it bad practice to have a thing like

```
public class Constants
{
    public static Mouse mouse;
    public static Keyboard keyboard;
}
```

(Mouse and Keyboard are objects that return input)

Or would it be preferrable to have an object with these fields, passed to the objects that need them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is what you're after.

Pay special attention to [The solution of Bill Pugh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh) section - this is a very clean implementation of a thread-safe lazy-initialisation singleton leveraging the java language specification to make it thread safe.

The singleton pattern is generally frowned upon now as it makes unit testing almost impossible. Usually this is now done via dependency injection frameworks like [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/).

Depending on where you are running your application, often there is some sort of "context" you can store singletons in - for example the `ServletContext` in a web application. This gives you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Its usually better to put these into an object, or at least provide getter's and setters for them.  The reason being you can often run into concurrency issues when you are directly accessing an object from multiple threads (which happens a lot with graphics and interfaces).  So unless you know the object you are accessing is thread safe, its better to handle the concurrency yourself in a logical fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. Remember that if you want the object in the Constants class to be modified from an outside source, you must declare Constants as static. Make sure the object's location is thread safe, however. A lot of people will probably post fancy terms here, but what you have should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get familiar with *Singleton* Design Pattern. The famous Design Patterns by gang of four are commonly appreciated solutions for common programming problems.
Look it up on Wikipedia or Google.